# How to write animate style in javascript for an element

Tags: javascript, css

Here, the `animation: slideUp 0.7s  ease-in-out;` where 0.7s is dynamic and its needs to be calculated and added from javascript.

How to write below style/css in javascript:-

```
$(".narra").css("animation", "slideUp "+ i * 0.1+"s  ease-in-out");
```

## .css

```
.narra{
 /* animation: slideUp 0.7s  ease-in-out; */
}

@keyframes slideUp{
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm guessing that `$(".narra").css("animation", "slideUp "...` is in a loop, in which case you're overriding the `niamtion` property of the same element in each iteration, can you add  your full code please ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to easily modify the CSS once it has been sent by the server. However you can use jQuery or Javascript to modify the [animation-duration](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp) property of the object(s) that you want.

There are additional [animation](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_animation.asp) components that you can break your CSS up into to allow for easier or more readable base classes, then use the Javascript to set the duration

```css
.narra {
    animation-name: 'slideUp',
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out
}
```

```js
 var calc = i * 0.1 // your math here;
 $(".narra").css("animation-duration", calc + "s");
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/46r9zs5q/11/)

Comment: Sorry, this is not working  similar to  "animation: slideUp 0.7s  ease-in-out;" .

Comment: @Mahi I've made a fiddle for you, let me know if you have any questions https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/46r9zs5q/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.style` aproach, like this:

```
$(".narra").style.animation = "slideUp "+ i * 0.1+"s  ease-in-out";
```

Let me know if that helped :)